# System.ArgumentException: 'The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime-error, runtime

One day after pulling commits from upstream and run the C# solution (projects) I got this error message in the title. The compilation was successful completely but at run time I got this error see attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to clean your projects/solution including docker-compose project. If after doing all this and it still does not work, you will have to into your package-lock.json and ensure that the changes you made before this error happens reflected and up to date. In my case specifically I changed the project folder name and that was not updated in package-lock.json in directives "name":

{
**"name": "NameChanged",**
"lockfileVersion": 2,
"requires": true,
"packages": {

That is it!

(the clean and rebuild should take care of it).

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete all `bin` and `obj` directories in every project, include root where your .sln file.